# Swift: Create array of coordinates

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create an array where the location of the user will be stored. I tried to use the code below but it won't work, it just change the coordinates inside the array.

```
func prevcurrLoc(lat : Double, lng: Double) {
    var destination = [[String:Double]]()
        
    let locArray : [String:Double] = ["lat" : lat, "lng" : lng]
        
    destination.append(locArray)
        
    print(destination)
}
```

I also try the code below, but  it work the same, it only change the coordinates inside the array.

```
func prevcurrLoc(lat : Double, lng: Double) {
        
    var coordArray : [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
        
    let latArray = [lat]
    let lngArray = [lng]
        
    if latArray.count == lngArray.count {
         for i in 0 ..< latArray.count {
             let destination = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latArray[i], lngArray[i])
                
             coordArray.append(destination)
                
             print(coordArray)
         }
    }
}
```

I hope you understand what I mean. I am very grateful of any help! Thank you for reading.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What is your desired output? Can you give an example using numbers or arrays of what you want to do?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what is going on or supposed to be going on here. You have a function named "previewcurrLoc" -- is that supposed to give the previous or current location? Also, you're `destination` array is created *within* that function. You probably want it to be stored elsewhere so that you can actually append to it. Right now, it gets created each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have an array declared outside of the function if you want the locations to be remaining after the function has exited.

Assuming you have this function in a struct you need a property for the array

```
struct LocationData {
    var locations = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
     //…
}
```

And then add locations to this array (I have renamed the function)

```
struct LocationData {
    var locations = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

    func addLocation(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        let destination = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        locations.append(destination)
    }                
}
```